# Fish theme "bobthefish" not showing special symbols

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fish, powerline

So I installed fish and oh-my-fish, installed the "bobthefish" theme for it, It wasnt showing specials symbols so I figured I needed the Powerline font, but even after installing it and doing it everything it still wont show them, what am I doing wrong?

I am using WSL with Ubuntu.
I installed Powerline by cloning the git repo and running the install.sh, then `fc-cache -vf`

[image: This is how my fish looks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to install the font on windows not my WSL, I followed this post https://slmeng.medium.com/how-to-install-powerline-fonts-in-windows-b2eedecace58

Comment: Did you change any settings for it to work? I have tried everything, it still does not work